# Spare part identification for replacement purchase toolbox latch/catch/clip/hinge/toggle for holding the case closed

Tags: storage, latches, identify-a-tool

I'm looking for a replacement for this in my toolbox because it broke:

[image: locking latch/catch/clip/hinge/toggle for holding the case closed]

Can you also help me find the correct word to use. I think of locking latch/catch/clip/hinge/toggle for holding the case closed but not sure which one would be "official" or common-use to describe it.

I searched with Google Lens using a photo of my toolbox and came up with below, which appears to be exactly the same as my toolbox.

https://www.mscdirect.com/product/details/00071613 (no incentive, affiliation or referral benefit to me).

[image: Copolymer Resin Tool Box: 1 Compartment - grey tool box 2 locking latch/catch/clip/hinges]

"FLAMBEAU Copolymer Resin Tool Box: 1 Compartment"

I'm not able to find a place that sells replacement individual parts - can you help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, it's a plastic toolbox, for which the "replacement part" is a whole new plastic toolbox. Planned obsolescence ensures that the latches will break and that replacements will not be sold.

Or you *could* replace it with a non-plastic toolbox you might conceivably be able to find parts for, or that you could bodge generic parts onto without being unreasonable.

If you can find someone who's in the "excited, time is of no consequence" phase of their 3D printer ownership curve, they might be able to make something that might work. Faithfully replicating what's there will of course give you a part designed to fail, so some improvement in the design is likely required for a lasting fix, but you're limited by having to work with what the box gives you for connection points.

Or, buy a few feet of double-sided velcro and wrap all the way around the box, overlapping sufficiently to hold the weight of tools you keep in there. That will work.

Comment: +1 accepted answer, thank you! So it's off to the local recycling company it goes, whose profits go into their parent charity who help the homeless. And I have just moved all the tools into an underused empty DeWalt DEW179209-TBK Open Mouth Bag I had (again no affiliation). Thanks again.